# Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{1\}\quad\exists !y \in \mathbb{R}\quad\frac{y}{y+1} = x.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{1\}\quad\exists !y \in \mathbb{R}\quad\frac{y}{y+1} = x.$

After plotting this as a graph it seems to be the case, however I am not sure how I would go about proving this. Would it be possible to treat it like a function and attempt to show that it is surjective $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{1\}$? If this is possible how would I go about this?

Comment: Why don't you see whether $x=\frac{y}{y+1}$ has any solutions for $y$ and if so, how many???

Answer (score 2):

Good idea, let us clean it up.

- "It is surjective $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{1\}$" makes no sense: surjectivity is a global property, it does not depend on some $x$.
- "$\exists$" is related to surjectivity, but "$\exists!$" is related to bijectivity.
- $\frac y{y+1}$ is defined only if $y+1\ne0.$
- We first must *define* the function which ought to be bijective.

Consider the function
$$f:\mathbb R\setminus\{-1\}\to\mathbb R\setminus\{1\},\quad y\mapsto\frac y{y+1}.$$
Note that $f$ is well defined: if $y\ne-1,$ $\frac y{y+1}$ is a real number, distinct from $1.$

Now, the sentence you wanted to prove, or more correctly the sentence
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}\quad\exists!y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}\quad\frac y{y+1} = x,$$
is exactly the bijectivity of $f.$

It can be proved by analysis (check that $f'(y)>0$ and determine the limits of $f$ at $\pm\infty$ and $(-1)^\pm$) or more simply by direct computation, as suggested in ancient mathematician's comment: $\forall x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{1\},\forall y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\},$
$$\frac y{y+1}=x\Leftrightarrow y=x\left(y+1\right)\Leftrightarrow y\left(1-x\right)=x\Leftrightarrow y=\frac x{1-x},$$
and these equivalences simultaneously prove the existence and the uniqueness of the solution $y$ (given $x$) of your equation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$, because $y/(y+1)$ is not defined in $y=-1$.
Your idea of introducing function and considering surjectivity is good, but surjectivity isn't enough because that would show the existence but not the uniqueness. So, for $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$, it is:
$$\frac{y}{y+1}=x\iff y=x(y+1)\iff y=xy+x$$
$$\iff y-xy=x \iff y(1-x)=x\iff y=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
This solution is unique, because the function $x(y)=\frac{y}{y+1}$ is injective in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$, since for any $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ it is:
$$x(y_1)=x(y_2) \iff \frac{y_1}{y_1+1}=\frac{y_2}{y_2+1}\iff y_1y_2+y_1=y_2y_1+y_2\iff y_1=y_2$$

Comment: Don't you actually want to show that $y\mapsto y/(y+1)$ is injective, rather than its inverse?

Comment: @Ennar: Sure, thanks for noticing.